# blender game engine import error

Tags: python, blender

i just started learning blender and its scripting and tried to run its sample code

```
import bge


def main():

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner

sens = cont.sensors['mySensor']
actu = cont.actuators['myActuator']

if sens.positive:
    cont.activate(actu)
else:
    cont.deactivate(actu)
main()
```

and get the following error:
ImportError: No module named 'bge'
i searched for a solution but couldn't find any.how to solve this problem?
i am using blender 2.65

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Running import bge does not work when you press "Run script" or try to issue this command in the terminal. You have to press "P" to activate game engine mode. To run your script, connect a controller to the script.

Answer (score 0):

1. import 'bge' must be 'blender game', rather than blender rendering
2. give an 'always' run python scripts in 'game logic editor'
3. start game